# solution deployment stuck in deploying mode (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to deploy SharePoint solution using stsadm in SharePoint 2010. I used following command:
stsadm -o deploysolution -name solutionname.wsp -immediate -url siteurl -force -allowgacdeployment.

using this command solution not deploying. it stuck at "Deploying" Status. When I deploy solution manually from central admin it works fine and deployed successfully.

Comment: Check that the Timer Job service is running on at least one server in the farm. Why are you choosing to use stsadm in favor of the PowerShell cmdlets in this case, out of curiousity?

Answer (score 1):

I'd also suggest to make sure the timer service is running on every sharepoint server.
Restarting the service sometimes helps. Or a less invasive action would be to force job exection **running stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs** (I don't know if there's a powershell equivalent to that - didn't have any issues with solutions not deploying since 2007).

Also I had situations where an assembly in the GAC was locked by IIS and could therefore not be replaced. Maybe run "net stop/start w3svc" or iisreset.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple front-end servers then it must be one of two reasons:

1. Check if the 14 folder is read only
2. Check if the SharePoint Administration Service is started on all front-ends

Start Administration Service:
[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513050(v=office.14).aspx)

Sharepoint 14 folder location (This directory is the installation directory for core SharePoint Server files): `Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14`

I've had this problem a few days ago and it was the administration services.
If it's not on for all front-ends it can't deploy on all, just the once that are on.
 And in the central administration it stays as "Deploying"

Answer (score 0):

1. restart  **Sharepoint Administration Service** and then **SharePoint
   timer service** in all non-db servers on your farm
2. if not worked check related stuck in deploying solution in central
   admin **Farm Solutions** with below URL and try to **cancel deployment** and
   redeploy it

http://servername/_admin/Solutions.aspx

Comment: it works for me for the 3rd times